# How to compare two lists for the greater values in Python

Tags: python, list

I need to compare two lists given as parameters in a function. The third parameter in the function is an integer. The first list is a list of thresholds. The second list of smaller length than the first. When comparing the two lists, if the value in the second list is greater than the corresponding value in the first list for the consecutive number given as an input, then the function returns that index. How can I write a code for this? Particularly the code for comparing the two lists for the greater value.

Comment: Please explain your problem with code or example?

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare_lists(lst_a, lst_b, num):
    count = 0  # number of consecutive times a < b
    result = None  # last index value to be returned
    for index, value in enumerate(lst_a):
        try:
            if value < lst_b[index]:
                count += 1
            else:
                count = 0
            if count == num:
                result = index  # if you need the first index, then set result = index - num + 1
                break
        except IndexError:
            break

    return result


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [10, 20, 30]
print(compare_lists(a, b, 3))
```